# Switching branches does not refresh Solution Explorer in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I am probably missing something basic here, but I'm playing around with the Git version of TFS.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 preview (maybe that is my problem), so from a solution I created a master and I made a branch from this master; I'll call it version2.

I made changes to version 2, but I did not commit merge sync or anything.  So after messing around with version 2 I went back into Team Explorer, went to the branches tab, and double clicked main (I also tried right click switch).

I was hoping my Solution Explorer would not show the changes I made to version 2, because I had now switched to main. But that is not the case, and I am still seeing all the changes I made in version 2 in Solution Explorer. So how do I get Solution Explorer to reflect the branch I am currently working on?

Comment: If I've understood that correctly, that's not how it works. If you want to load a new solution, you will need to double-click the .sln file in the main branch. This will not display the differences though. For that, you can select a branch or individual file and right-click compare. Sounds like you want to right-click the main branch and compare with your local version 2 branch to see the changes that you have made but not yet commited.

Comment: Ok Let me ask it a different way say I have main on my local repository from main I make 2 branches event1 and event2.   I make some changes to event1  now I want to switch to event2 and make different changes. I don't want to see what I have done in event1 showing up in event2 in the solution explorer.   so event1 lets say I added a new aspx page I see the new aspx page in the solution explorer. I go to team explorer double click event2 open up solution explorer and I do not want to see the new aspx page that was created in event1. does that make sense?

Comment: Team Explorer and Solution Explorer are not linked. Team Explorer will allow you to view what's on the server and perform various source control tasks. Where Solution Explorer will show you what is in the current solution that you have open in Visual Studio. On the branch that you want to work on, right-click the branch name and click 'Get Latest', open the .sln (use Windows Explorer for clarity). Make your changes and close. Repeat for branch 2 (get latest and open), you shouldn't see your changes from branch 1. Hope this helps!

Comment: 'Get Latest' is not an option on right click.  view-->team explorer->branches     it shows active git Repositories with my branches. right clicking on a branch gives me the options, switch; new local branch from; Merge; Delete; View History; or Publish Branch.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Git's model is fundamentally different than TFVC. You need to commit the file to your branch (you don't necessarily need to push the change or the branch to the remote server). Once you commit the change, switching branches will behave in the fashion you're expecting.

Git is based on the model of committing changes to local branches frequently. Even if the code doesn't yet compile, it's fine to commit it to a local branch... you can always rebase or cherry-pick later on.

Comment: `Normally, you can't even switch branches with uncommitted changes`. Can someone qualify this? Does he mean in Visual Studio? Using GIT command line tools? The answer by @MrHinsh contradicts this assertion.

Comment: @gravidThoughts At the time I wrote the answer, that was the case in Visual Studio. Thanks for pointing out that the answer is no longer accurate; I'll update it for correctness shortly.

Comment: This was my issue. Still learning Git with TFS but looks like I need to get in the mindset of always doing a local commit.

Answer (score 17):

By default in Git if you have pending changes that you have not committed and you switch branch the changes are moved to the new branch. Git is assuming that this is what you want.

If you want to leave the changes on v2 you need to commit the changes with that branch checkout. You can then switch to the v1 branch and see the solution change.

Comment: This is exactly how my solution is behaving. I did not know this.  Thx.

Comment: Turns out you're not alone being surprised by this. See http://gitless.com/ for an interesting project aiming to improve such things.